# AsyncTask to wait for Location

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gps, android-location

I have a problem and concept which I cannot understand.
My application obtains information from Internet base on current location.
The information is obtained in AsyncTask.

My problem is that I don't want to proceed with getting the information before I get GPS Coordinates.

I have GPS Service which works fine and returns coordinates. However I want my AsyncTask for obtaining the information from Internet to wait until GPS Coordinates are available.

This also kinda works fine - in my AsyncTask for GPS I start the serviceIntent which get my coordinates. However onPostExecute does not wait until I have the coordinates and moves on.

How to make AsyncTask wait until coordinates are available?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need your AsyncTask wait until coordinates are available.

In your AsyncTask, you query GPS coordinates, when you get GPS coordinates response, you can start another AsyncTask with known GPS coordinates to send request to your server and wait response.

Maybe you do not need the first AsyncTask, just call location service to get current location and start AsyncTask in location service *onLocationChanged()* callback. you also need do error handle when locate failed such as location is disabled.

If you really want *onPostExecute()* get called after *onLocationChanged()*, you can wait a lock object in your AsyncTask's *onExecute()*, in location service callback, send a notify on wait object.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't call the AsyncTask from onLocationChange(). How can I make AsyncTask to "listen" for the coordinates? OnPostExecute() gets called in the middle of the process - it does not wait for coordinates.